# Generate auto increment id from JSON schema faker

Tags: json, schema, faker, mockups

I'm looking for way to generate data by JSON schema faker js with IDs incremented from 0.
When I'm trying to use `autoIncrement` parameter in schema, I get valid values, but this auto increment is started from random number.
Is that possible to do that with this package?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an official solution to the problem, but here is a workaround.

`json-schema-faker`'s source code for generating auto-incremented integers (node_modules\json-schema-faker\lib\index.js) explains why it starts from a random integer:

```
// safe auto-increment values
container.define('autoIncrement', function (value, schema) {
    if (!this.offset) {
        var min = schema.minimum || 1;
        var max = min + env.MAX_NUMBER;
        this.offset = random$1.number(min, max);
    }
    if (value === true) {
        return this.offset++;
    }
    return schema;
});
```

It is the `if (!this.offset)` branch that sets up the initial value. To achieve our goal, we can modify the code inside the branch like this:

```
if (!this.offset) {
    var min = schema.minimum || 1;
    // var max = min + env.MAX_NUMBER;
    // this.offset = random$1.number(min, max);
    this.offset = min;
}
```

When `minimum` is specified in the schema, its value will be used as the starting point. Otherwise, `1` is used instead.

It is also noteworthy that, if you specify `minimum` with an extremely large number, the auto-incrementation will no longer be "safe".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for a more current answer, you can now set an 'initialOffset' value within the schema which acts as a start value